# is there a way do ftp upload with confirmation from C#?

Tags: c#, ftp

I wonder if ftp process can give me any upload success confirmation.
I'm looking at one of the code project and except of the potential exception
don't see any way to get a real success confirmation.

```
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
    {
        try
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
            byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

            try
            {
                while (bytesSent != 0)
                {
                    ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                    bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            localFileStream.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: This might be a silly question; but as soon as the method is finished **without** an exception, isn't that success in itself?

Comment: Just a tip:  You should not call `Close()` inside the `try`-clause, but instead in a `finally`-clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the file has been uploaded, but before you clean up (closing streams, nulling out the `FtpWebRequest`) you can call `GetResponse()` on the `FtpWebRequest` like this:

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) ftpRequest.GetResponse();
```

The `FtpWebResponse` object have fields like `StatusCode` that should give you an indication of success.

**Full code example:**

Below is your method refactored, with upload status (I haven't actually tried your code as it does not compile by itself):

```
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    FileStream localFileStream;
    FtpWebResponse ftpResponse;

    try
    {
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest) FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesSent != 0)
        {
            ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
            bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("Upload status: {0}, {1}", ftpResponse.StatusCode, ftpResponse.StatusDescription);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        // throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (localFileStream != null)
        {
            localFileStream.Close();
        }
        if (ftpStream != null)
        {
            ftpStream.Close();
        }   
        if (ftpResponse != null)
        {
            ftpResponse.Close();
        }            
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I guess this should do the trick the only question is if the ftpResponse statement will start for sure after the whole file is transferred.